# Vue 3 and Vuetify 3 Alpha: ValidationError: progress plugin invalid options

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

After creating a Vue 3 project, adding Vuetify 3 Alpha, when I run "npm run serve", this is the error I get. I tried without adding Vuetify 3 Alpha and the Vue 3 project starts fine, it's just after adding the Vuetify that the error appears.

```
INFO  Starting development server...
ERROR  ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
    options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

at validateOptions (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:32:11)
at new ProgressPlugin (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:62:3)
at new Progress (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:25:21)
at new progressPlugin (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:127:10)
at c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:14:18
at Object.toConfig (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:78:22)
at c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:63
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.toConfig (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:40)
at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (c:\wamp64\www\vuetify-3\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:261:34)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same error after running `vue add vuetify`

Run `npm update` and re-create the project again.

Also make sure you are on the latest versions of the following.

```
node -v && vue -V && npm -v
```

- v17.0.1
- @vue/cli 5.0.0-rc.0
- 8.1.0

Comment: Hi, I managed to get pass this error thanks to your help.

Comment: I got another issue though, my components aren't being loaded. Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Hm maybe? my html was showing up with no vuetify, thats were setting it up as a new project solved it for me. So my components where loading.. Check your router setup maybe?

Comment: Node v17.0.1 is not LTS. Do I really have to install an instable version to get about this?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan LTS version did not work for me at the moment of posting this answer.

Comment: I installed node 18.1.0 and it didn't help me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. **Node:** v17.0.1. **vue:** @vue/cli 5.0.8. **npm:** 8.1.0. I did `npm update` it did work after getting those new versions but I still get an error: **ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.**

Answer (score 3):

@Mishka's solution worked for me, but I did `npm update --force` to make it working.