# How to use vue3 with vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

I want to use Vuetify with Vue3 , I'm getting some errors :
npm version : 8.1.2
node version :v16
vue cli :4

when I run vue add vuetify I got this warn :
[image]

and when I run the project using npm run serve I got this error :
[image]

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931346/vue-3-and-vuetify-3-alpha-validationerror-progress-plugin-invalid-options

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Vuetify does not support Vue 3. Support for Vue 3 will come with the release of Vuetify v3

#v3.0 (Titan)
Target Release: May 2022
Alpha: Live
Beta: February 2022

When creating a new project, please ensure you selected Vue 2 from the Vue CLI prompts, or that you are installing to an existing Vue 2 project.

more info @: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#vue-cli-install